# how to use variable variables PHP function on my code?

Tags: php, variables

Normally i use this code and it's will be echo work good.

```
<?PHP 
echo $row->test_column_1;
?>
```

But when i tyied to use this code, it's not echo any data. How can i do ?

```
<?PHP
$i = "1";
echo ${'row->test_column_' . $i};
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Object Variable variables name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919011/php-object-variable-variables-name)

Answer (score 2):

You can access a dynamic property name like this:

```
<?php
$i = "1";
echo $row->{'test_column_' . $i};
```